# configure router for DNS queries for specific domain

Tags: networking, router, dns, webserver, hosts

I want to configure my [Netgear N-150 router](http://documentation.netgear.com/wnr1000v2/enu/202-10546-01/index.htm) so that it answers DNS queries **within** the LAN.  This is in context of running different kinds of servers:  e-mail, news, web or VoIP from home.

Nothing is public facing, just within my network.  If it's public facing, that's ok, but not required.  The pc running the "server" is `tleilax`, and `doge` is the client pc.

Right now, the hosts file for`doge` is as so:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   doge.bounceme.net   doge
192.168.1.3 tleilax.bounceme.net    tleilax

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
thufir@doge:~$
```

so that I can test the VoIP connection:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo sipsak -vv -s sip:thufir101@tleilax
No SRV record: _sip._tcp.tleilax
No SRV record: _sip._udp.tleilax
using A record: tleilax

message received:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.1.1:43624;branch=z9hG4bK.7332b2de;rport=43624;alias;received=192.168.1.3
User-Agent: Ekiga/4.0.1
From: sip:sipsak@127.0.1.1:43624;tag=73f04e12
Call-ID: 1945128466@127.0.1.1
To: sip:thufir101@tleilax
Contact: <sip:thufir101@192.168.1.3>
Content-Length: 0



** reply received after 1.142 ms **
   SIP/2.0 200 OK
   final received
thufir@doge:~$
```

I want to configure the [router](http://documentation.netgear.com/wnr1000v2/enu/202-10546-01/index.htm) so that when another computer connects, say a Mac, it also can find `tleilax` or `tleilax.bounceme.net`.

I don't want to open up my router to random DNS queries from everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this might be possible. Because SIP needs special DNS records which might be not configurable on a netgear router. Normally you have to create record like this:

Type    Service Protocol    Port    Weight  Priority    TTL Name    Target
SRV _sip    _tls    443 1   100 1 Hour  thedomain.co.uk sipdir.online.lync.com
SRV _sipfederationtls   _tcp    5061    1   100 1 Hour  thedomain.co.uk

ciao
ryder